# AngularJs $stateProvider doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am sorry, but I am new to Angular.  I tried to use $stateProvider in my application, but I only get a blank screen.

I did include the script for angular-ui-router.min.js, then I injected ui.router module. I config the code in my config() section. However, I can only see a blank screen..

I tried to add some code to prove my angular works, and it does (the timer works), but the $stateProvider just don't want to work.  What wrong with me?! .

Below is my code: (I am using MS Visual studio 2010 to edit)..

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head >
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
            .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/',
                        template: '<h1>Home</h1>'
                    })
            }])
            .controller('mCtrl', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
                var self = this;

                var tick = function () {
                    self.currentTime = Date.now();

                    $timeout(tick, 1000);
                };

                $timeout(tick, 1000);

            } ]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mCtrl as m">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       Current Time - {{m.currentTime | date: 'EEE, MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have not set the default route for your state, use **[$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#user-content-urlrouterprovider)** to set your default state.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qd0oWqUDPWsup5JIeDix?p=preview)**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head >
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
            .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/',
                        template: '<h1>Home</h1>'
                    });
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            }])
            .controller('mCtrl', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
                var self = this;

                var tick = function () {
                    self.currentTime = Date.now();

                    $timeout(tick, 1000);
                };

                $timeout(tick, 1000);

            } ]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mCtrl as m">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       Current Time - {{m.currentTime | date: 'EEE, MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. You are GREAT!! Thank you. The examples (such as http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/) I had been reading never tell me that... I believe, it is a good article, but ...